# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have set the value of `n` to `0` so that with the help of `iloc[]` I can compare and iterate over certain columns.

```
n = 0
for n in request_id:
    if dframe1.iloc[: , n+1] != dframe1.iloc[: , n]:
       if dframe1.iloc[: , n] == 0:
        print 'logged'
       else:
        print 'solved'
    elif dframe.iloc[: , n+1] == dframe1.iloc[: , n]:
       if dframe.iloc[: , n] == 0:
        print 'not logged'
       else:
        print 'Repeated'
```

I am getting this error when I run my program.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-30-a5672dab4bb1> in <module>()
  1 n = 0
  2 for n in request_id:----> 3 if dframe1.iloc[: , n+1] != dframe1.iloc[: , n]:
  4         if dframe1.iloc[: , n] == 0:
  5             print 'logged'TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Comment: Please include your code and results as text within the question, not as pictures.

Comment: I have edited the question , as per your request @Dragonthoughts. I am not able to get the error message correctly into the coding console , sorry for that.